# "viable" in a question

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, word-order

> Are both examples viable?

compared to

> Are both viable examples?

Could the adjective "viable" change its position in question without violating grammar rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both are grammatical. We are dealing with ellipsis.

> Both examples are viable examples

can be made more compact without loss of sense by

> Both examples are viable

or by

> Both are viable examples

The first form of ellipsis is turned into a question

> Are both examples viable?

The second form is turned into a question

> Are both viable examples?

As a matter of rhetoric, I prefer

> Are both examples viable?

because an adjective at the end is more emphasized than one in the middle, but that is rhetorical judgment rather than grammatical rule.

Comment: And while there's nothing ungrammatical about *Are both viable example?* we would normally say *Are **they** both viable examples?* However, we would not add a *they* to the reversed version of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Only a small difference. Consider using a simpler adjective and noun "red" and "cat".

> Are both [of them] red cats?

This asks both about the colour and the species. The answer could be "No, they are red dogs" or "No, they are black cats". (or "Yes, they are")

> Are both cats red?

This assumes they are cats, and asks only about the colour. The answer could be "No, they are black" (or "Yes they are")

So saying "Are both of them viable examples" could be answered "No, they are not  examples", or "No they are not viable".  On the other hand "Are both examples viable?" is only asking about the viability of the examples.

Comment: I know this type of comments are discouraged here, but you made a great point. When I looked at the question, my immediate thought was that they are essentially saying the same thing, but that is not the case all the time.